# Restore database from individual datafile backups

Tags: oracle, backup, restore, rman

I had a script that backs up all the individual datafiles like:

```
RMAN> BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATAFILE 'datafile<1>.dbf'
```

So i have backupsets of all the datafiles. I'm confused as to whether it would be sufficient to use `RESTORE DATABASE`, as can be done after a full database backup using `BACKUP DATABASE`? Isn't the end result of both `BACKUP` operations the same?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you backup this way?

Comment: restore database validate; will tell you if the DB is restorable from the backups you have taken.

Comment: @colin Full backup was too slow and i don't think multi channel is possible with 10g

Comment: @Phil Thanks! All the individual datafiles could be validated. But I'm not sure if that implies that the entire database, and not just the datafiles can be restored

Comment: @Jay Multiple channels are indeed available in Oracle 10g, but as with 9i and 11g this requires Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jay, this isn't officially documented, so I'm speaking only from my own experience.

In RMAN, the command `BACKUP DATABASE ...` is synonymous with `BACKUP DATAFILE 1, 2, ..., n-th ...`.

Also the command `RESTORE DATABASE ...`  is synonymous with  `RESTORE DATAFILE 1, 2, ..., n-th ...`.

I'm not sure about `RECOVER DATABASE`; it might be also a synonym of `RECOVER DATAFILE 1,2, ... n-th` , although  I've never tested the latter. In your scenario, the former would work as expected.

In particular, neither `RESTORE DATABASE` or `RECOVER DATABASE` require all the datafiles to come from "a single backup of database" (from a single run of `BACKUP DATABASE`). Actually, RMAN doesn't even have a concept of "a single backup of database".